# Displaying z value in plot with pcolor: why it works for one of the two figure but not the other?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to display below the cursor, coordinates (x,y,z) on a 2D plots. Consider this minimal working example (I compactified as much as I could from my longer code).

If you run it, you will see that the Z coordinate is the good one for the second graph but not for the same. But the Z values that should be taken by the function format_coord that I provide to ax.format_coord are updated between my two plots.

Then, I am not sure to understand this behavior.

How can I fix it ?

As a sidenote: I took the function from format_coord from a stackexchange post... That I do not find anymore... If I find it I will attach the link (I am not super confortable with tricks with pyplot, consider me as a beginner).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

def format_coord(x, y):
    xarr = X[0,:]
    yarr = Y[:,0]
    if ((x > xarr.min()) & (x <= xarr.max()) & 
        (y > yarr.min()) & (y <= yarr.max())):
        col = np.searchsorted(xarr, x)-1
        row = np.searchsorted(yarr, y)-1
        z = Z[row, col]
        return f'x={x:1.4f}, y={y:1.4f}, z={z:1.4f}   [{row},{col}]'
    else:
        return f'x={x:1.4f}, y={y:1.4f}'

u=list(map(lambda x:pow(10,x),np.arange(-2,1+0.1,0.1).tolist()))
v=list(map(lambda x:pow(10,x),np.arange(-2,1+0.1,0.1).tolist()))

[X,Y]=np.meshgrid(u,v)
Z1=np.ones((len(u),len(v)))
Z2=3*np.ones((len(u),len(v)))

Z=Z1 # Here I change the Z that will be considered in the function
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pcm = ax.pcolor(X, Y, Z1,norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=Z1.min(), vmax=Z2.max()),
                   cmap='PuBu_r',edgecolors='black')
plt.xscale('log', basex=10)
plt.yscale('log', basey=10)
fig.colorbar(pcm, extend='max')
ax.format_coord = format_coord
plt.title('test1')
print(Z[0,0]) # displays 1 as expected
plt.show()

Z=Z2 # Here I change the Z that will be considered in the function
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pcm = ax.pcolor(X, Y, Z2,norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=Z1.min(), vmax=Z2.max()),
                   cmap='PuBu_r',edgecolors='black')
plt.xscale('log', basex=10)
plt.yscale('log', basey=10)
fig.colorbar(pcm, extend='max')
ax.format_coord = format_coord
plt.title('test2')
print(Z[0,0]) # displays 3 as expected
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you run your code in one lap, opening two different interactive windows. Note that `format_coord` is executed at the moment you move your cursor, at then looks at the actual value of `Z` at that moment.

To get `format_coord` to use two different `Z` arrays, you could work with an intermediate function as follows:

```py
def format_coord(x, y, Z):
    xarr = X[0,:]
    yarr = Y[:,0]
    if ((x > xarr.min()) & (x <= xarr.max()) &
        (y > yarr.min()) & (y <= yarr.max())):
        col = np.searchsorted(xarr, x)-1
        row = np.searchsorted(yarr, y)-1
        z = Z[row, col]
        return f'x={x:1.4f}, y={y:1.4f}, z={z:1.4f}   [{row},{col}]'
    else:
        return f'x={x:1.4f}, y={y:1.4f}'

def format_coord_Z1(x, y):
    return format_coord(x, y, Z1)

def format_coord_Z2(x, y):
    return format_coord(x, y, Z2)

# ....

# And then use this for the first plot
ax.format_coord = format_coord_Z1

# And  this for the second plot
ax.format_coord = format_coord_Z2
```

Note that there also exists a library [`mplcursors`](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that can be useful for this type of functionality. E.g. [this example](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/image.html).

Comment: It is exactly it. Oooh I see the problem then. Your workaround would work for this simple example but what if I have many plots to do with different Z values. Is there a way to avoid having to create as much function as much as plot I would do ? Thank you very much !

Comment: You could write it as `ax.format_coord = lambda x, y: format_coord(x, y, Z1)` to avoid creating the functions explicitly.